# Problem using eof() in a while loop [C++]

Tags: c++, ios, linux, eof

I have problem with the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
template <class A> void reading(A &a) {
    bool x = true;
    while(x) {
        x = false;
        std::cin >> a;
        while (std::cin.fail()) {
            if (std::cin.eof()) {
                std::cout <<"You pressed CTRL+D\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore (1000000000, '\n');
            }
            else {
                std::cout <<"Give me numbers, not letters\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(1000000000,'\n');
            }
            x = true;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    double o[3];
    for (double &i:o)
        reading (i);
    for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        std::cout<<o[j]<<std::endl;   
}
```

In particular, when I press ctrl+d the program enter in an infinite loop.
Does someone know where is the problem and what is the solution?

My goal is to make a template function that can read any kind of data and that disable the ctrl+d during the input.

Comment: Your OS is treating Ctrl+D as an end-of-file.  You could change to Windows, in which case Ctrl+Z will be the end-of-file.

Comment: Just as a side note: If you want to ignore an unlimited amount of input in `std::cin.ignore`, then you should set the first parameter to `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`. See the documentation on [`std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for further information.

Comment: "*when I press ctrl+d the program enter in an infinite loop*" - well yeah, because you never break your loop on anything other than a successful read of a `double` value.  If `operator>>` fails to extract a `double`, or encounters EOF, you clear the condition and keep looping.